# couldn't complete action submission after correction in hindi

Tags: actions-on-google

In google action after completing errors in invocation in hindi language I tried to submit, but it shows:

> API status code=403 you are not acces to this agent

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a bug which has since been resolved.